# Bulk renaming file names in Ubuntu/Linux with variable pattern

Tags: bash, ubuntu, for-loop, rename, file-rename

I am struggling to rename bunch of files with a variable pattern to be removed.

I have:

```
1B_ACTCGCTA-CCTAGAGT_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
1B_ACTCGCTA-CCTAGAGT_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

97C_TAAGGCGA-TTATGCGA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
97C_TAAGGCGA-TTATGCGA_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

98A_S62_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
98A_S62_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

and want to have:

```
1B_R1_001.fastq.gz
1B_R2_001.fastq.gz

97C_R1_001.fastq.gz
97C_R2_001.fastq.gz

98A_R1_001.fastq.gz
98A_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

As you can see the pattern that needs to be dropped is variable and simple matching wont work. 
A logical workaround would be to exclude everything between the first and third underscore, or first underscore and letter "R".
Unfortunately I am not able to come up with a code that would do that.
It can be anything as long as it works, rename, bash for in loop, etc...

Appreciate your help,
Deni

EDIT: I was trying to use for-loop but was not able to come up with a complete code to retain second part of the file name (everything that follows letter "R")

```
for file in *.fastq.gz; do echo mv "${file}" "${file/_*/\/}"; done
```

Comment: @Inian done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for f in *.fastq.gz; do echo mv "$f" "${f%%_*}_${f#*_*_*_}"; done
```

**I specifically added `echo` before `mv`, so it prints what it would move. If it prints correctly remove `echo` and run again.**

What happens here is I take head via %% and tail via # and concatenate them. See `Parameter Expansion` in `man bash` for meaning of %% and #. The solution relies on number of _ in file names being constant.

Comment: I've just included an edit to my original post, I was half-way onto it :)
I am aware of the echo.
This works like a charm. Thanks, you saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

With (Perl) `rename`:

```
rename --dry-run 's/_.*_R/_R/' *gz
```

**Sample Output**

```
'1B_ACTCGCTA-CCTAGAGT_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to '1B_R1_001.fastq.gz'
'1B_ACTCGCTA-CCTAGAGT_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to '1B_R2_001.fastq.gz'
'97C_TAAGGCGA-TTATGCGA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to '97C_R1_001.fastq.gz'
'97C_TAAGGCGA-TTATGCGA_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to '97C_R2_001.fastq.gz'
'98A_S62_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to '98A_R1_001.fastq.gz'
'98A_S62_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to '98A_R2_001.fastq.gz'
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer which doesn't rely on number of underscores:

```
for file in $(ls); do
    mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F _ 'BEGIN {OFS="_"} {print $1, $(NF-1), $NF}');
done
```